# Passing data to node backed

Tags: node.js, http, express, post, request

I do not know whats going on here and tried to fix it for a few hours now.

I have a simple post
[image]

So I am posting the data to

> http://localhost:8080/api/data

now in my root folder I have node file `index.js` I am trying to retrieve the posted values

```
  // grab the packages we need
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

// POST http://localhost:8080/api/users
// parameters sent with
app.post('/api/data', function(req, res) {
    var user_id = req.body.id;
    var token = req.body.token;
    var geo = req.body.geo;

    res.send(user_id + ' ' + token + ' ' + geo);
});
```

However when I start the node server and navigate to either

> http://localhost:8080/

or

> http://localhost:8080/api/data

I simple get : `Cannot Get`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: get !== post, you sure that you using the right method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// POST http://localhost:8080/api/users
// parameters sent with
app.post('/api/data', function(req, res) {
  // ...
});
```

> However when I start the node server and navigate to either http://localhost:8080/ or http://localhost:8080/api/data I simple get : Cannot Get

When you navigate to some URL your browser uses the GET method, not POST - however your request handler uses the POST method, not GET - which means that your API doesn't support the GET method for that route and that't what you see here.

If you want to test it with your browser you would either need to create an HTML form with the correct method or use a tool like Postman or cUrl:

- https://www.getpostman.com/
- https://curl.haxx.se/